# Execute code from setTimeOut after the response has been sent to the client in node js is a bad practice?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, http, settimeout

I want to call setTimeOut after the response has been sent to the client
for changing value in a database after 3 minutes, is there any problem with that?

```js
app.get("/route",(req,res,next) => {

// update value in db
// then send the value in the response
res.status(200).json({newValue : value}).end();

setTimeout(()=>{
// change the value in the db after 3 minutes
},180000)

})
```

Comment: I'm adding more info to my question here , the task I would like to perform is to insert some random code to MongoDB, for SMS code , but I would like to change the value after 3 minutes, is there any functionality in mongo that can do that? or my best solution is to do that in the node server?, and if I will still do that in my original way like above will it cause problems with other client calls to the server if I get a lot of traffic ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in using the `setTimeout` for doing some work, but that is a naive solution. The task will be lost if the server goes down. So a better approach would be to use some scheduler like [`node-cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) which will run on every minute polling the database to see if any of the rows matches a criteria. If you change the app to such an architecture, then you would just need to add a row to a table with an expiry of `T+3 minutes` and the cron job will check if there are any unprocessed entries in the table and act on those data.

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every minute');
  /* Get entries from database table which has a timestamp < now and is unprocessed and act on those data */
 
 // do the processing

 // mark the row as processed
});
```

Then your route will be just

```
app.get("/route",(req,res,next) => {

// update value in db
// then send the value in the response
res.status(200).json({newValue : value}).end();

// write a row to database table with expiry now() + 3 minutes

})
```

Comment: Thanks I will definitely look at this module! , do you know if it's working good with MongoDB as well ?

Comment: Yes it will work with mongoDB, in fact, it is a database agnostic approach.

Comment: In mongodb, a document can be expired automatically by setting `TTL`. See this https://medium.com/@Baresse/auto-expire-documents-with-mongodb-772fee84cc23

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with TTL and I use it to clear sessions, the problem is that my SMS code is not a document it's a field inside another document, guess I will try node-cron and will see